# Text alignment not working in setHTML in QTextDocument?

Tags: html, css, qt

I tried aligning my text using both CSS and HTML but none of them work. Somehow HTML align attribute works for h1 and h2 but not for div or span.

```
QTextDocument doc;
doc.setDefaultStyleSheet("div{ align-content: center ; font: italic 15px ; color:green;}");

doc.setHtml( 
          "<h1  align='center'>LOL </h1 > "
          "<h2  align='right'>lolh </h2 ><hr><br>"
          "<div align='centre'>"
          "<span align='centre'> lol1 : "+ compname +"</span><br><br>"
          "<span align='right'>lol2 : "+ worktype +"</span><br><br>"
          "</div>" 
          "<h2  align='right'>lolH </h2 ><hr><br>"
          "<span align='right'>lol3 :</span><br><br>"
           )
```

Out of every alignment attempt used, only the h1 and h2 attributes work and I have no idea why. Can you help me?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `'center'`, not `'centre'`?

Comment: @Radical Fanatic But the stylesheet has 'center', that doesn't work either. The right alignment doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried `text-align:center` in css?

Comment: @RadicalFanatic yeah, i did. No effect though

Answer (score 2):

Use `doc.setTextWidth(...)` to enable text alignment (see [QTBUG-22851](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-22851)).

Comment: Question asked in 2015. Question answered in 2017. Answer still relevant and used in 2021.